# Backup gsuite users contacts (with service account)

Tags: python, google-api, google-workspace, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I am admin of Gsuite.

## I have a task to collect backup of all contacts of all users our g suite service.

how to collect mail through gmail api - I understand., everything is ok.

but with contacts I am at a dead end:

1. created a service account
2. wide domain settings for a service account have permissions for https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts. And other scopes

3.1. when connecting to the Contacts-API i get "*The request is a valid API key.*" - Why? (same service account get all emails and calendar events...)
3.2. when connecting to a People-api:

- I can reat only the accounts myself (popeple/me)  if i use credentials.with_subject("myemail@mydomain"))
- if simple service account credentials - return *"Only "people/me" resource is supported."*

**Q:**

1. People-API  may get only "people/me" contacts?
2. What is API i may use for backup contacts from all users of my domain?

thanks, and sorry for english

SCOPES

- auth/gmail.readonly,
- auth/contacts,
- a/feeds/compliance/audit/,
- m8/feeds,

etc

*example for good code people-api, its worked with "me", but not working with other users:*

```
class BlaBla():
  ....
  def build_api(self, email, api, api_version, delegate = True):
      self.email = email
      credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(self.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes = self.SCOPES)
      if delegate:
          delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject(self.email)
          self.service = build(api, api_version, credentials=delegated_credentials)
      else:
          self.service = build(api, api_version, credentials=credentials)




  def get_user_contacts(self, email):
      self.build_api(email=email, api="people", api_version="v1", delegate = True)
      resourceName = "people/me"
      connections = self.service.people().connections().list(resourceName=resourceName, pageSize = 10, personFields='names,emailAddresses').execute()
      # connections - with my contacts
      self.build_api(email=email, api="people", api_version="v1", delegate = False)
      resourceName = "people/googleId..."
      connections = self.service.people().connections().list(resourceName=resourceName, pageSize = 10, personFields='names,emailAddresses').execute()
      # return  "Only "people/me" resource is supported."

bla=BlaBla()
bla.get_user_contacts(args.email)
```

Comment: are you asking how to get contacts from gmail? There is a section in this documentation concerning contacts with google api: https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/

Comment: in gdata lib i see auth with email and password, but i want get not my contacts and have no password. it is possible with service - account? https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client/blob/master/samples/contacts/contacts_example.py

Comment: did you try setting up a service account per this documentation? https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started